# image of part of uiwebview

Tags: javascript, image, uiwebview, touch

I have a question, I get a screenshot of an uiwebview with this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.myWebView.bounds.size, self.myWebView.opaque, 0.0);
[self.myWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

all work perfectly, now I need to take the screenshot of a particulary div, an user do a long press inside the uiwebview, then I detect the div touched and I make a photo of this particulary div. What is the best way for do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to do renderInContext.

```
 // Size of the result rendered image
CGSize targetImageSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
// Check for retina image rendering option
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetImageSize, NO, 0);
else UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetImageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// The view to be rendered
[[yourImageView layer] renderInContext:context];
// Get the rendered image
UIImage *original_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and for other part as far as i know There is no public method which allows you to take a screenshot of the entire screen (i.e. with the status bar). There is a [private method](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html) though UIGetScreenImage which allows you to use achieve this functionality. But, since it's a private method you will get your app rejected if you submit it to the App Store.

Comment: this is equal of my code :) thee is a way to change layer position? not only the dimension?